# How can I read WebSocket data and convert it to JSON format (Blob to JSON) from Kite Connect?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, websocket, blob

Preface: I am new to websockets

I am able to open, close and receive messages once I connect to the WebSocket but I have no idea how to read the incoming data.

The message I receive looks like the following:

```
MessageEvent {isTrusted: true, data: Blob, origin: "wss://ws.kite.trade", lastEventId: "", source: null, …}
          bubbles: false
          cancelBubble: false
          cancelable: false
          composed: false
          currentTarget: WebSocket {url: "wss://ws.kite.trade/?api_key=xxxxx&access_token=xxxx", readyState: 3, bufferedAmount: 0, onerror: null, onopen: ƒ, …}
          data: Blob {size: 48, type: ""}
          defaultPrevented: false
          eventPhase: 0
          isTrusted: true
          lastEventId: ""
          origin: "wss://ws.kite.trade"
          path: []
          ports: []
          returnValue: true
          source: null
          srcElement: WebSocket {url: "wss://ws.kite.trade/?api_key=xxxxx&access_token=xxxxxxxx", readyState: 3, bufferedAmount: 0, onerror: null, onopen: ƒ, …}
          target: WebSocket {url: "wss://ws.kite.trade/?api_key=xxxxx&access_token=xxxxxxxx", readyState: 3, bufferedAmount: 0, onerror: null, onopen: ƒ, …}
          timeStamp: 74468.20000000298
          type: "message"
          userActivation: null
```

the `e.data` looks like:

```
Blob {size: 48, type: ""}
  size: 48
  type: ""
  [[Prototype]]: Blob
    arrayBuffer: ƒ arrayBuffer()
    size: (...)
    slice: ƒ slice()
    stream: ƒ stream()
    text: ƒ text()
    type: (...)
    constructor: ƒ Blob()
    Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Blob"
    get size: ƒ size()
    get type: ƒ type()
```

Here is what I have done so far, in my React App:

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-resonance-es2y7?file=/src/components/SomeComponent.js)

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { Typography } from "@material-ui/core";

const DUMMY_HOLDINGS = [
  {
    tradingsymbol: "IRFC",
    instrument_token: 519425,
    last_price: 23.45
  },
  {
    tradingsymbol: "M&M",
    instrument_token: 519937,
    last_price: 755
  },
  {
    tradingsymbol: "SINTEXPLAST",
    instrument_token: 138407172,
    last_price: 5.65
  },
  {
    tradingsymbol: "ZOMATO",
    instrument_token: 1304833,
    last_price: 138.7
  },
  {
    tradingsymbol: "ZYDUSWELL",
    instrument_token: 136021764,
    last_price: 2170
  }
];

const SomeComponent = (props) => {
  const ACCESS_TOKEN = `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`; //redacted for obvious reasons
  const API_KEY = `xxxxxxxxxx`; //redacted for obvious reasons
  const ws_url = `wss://ws.kite.trade?api_key=${API_KEY}&access_token=${ACCESS_TOKEN}`;
  console.log(`WebSocket URL is: `, ws_url);

  const ws = useRef(null); // as a pointer to the websocket connection

  // The first useEffect gets the holdings if there are none, and
  // then creates a websocket connection
  useEffect(() => {
    // creates a new WebSocket
    ws.current = new WebSocket(ws_url);
    // the websocket requries one to "subscribe" to the instruments one wants
    // live data for, for each instrument it requires it's instrument_token
    // extracted from the DUMMY_ARRAY
    // refer to the docs for more info: https://kite.trade/docs/connect/v3/websocket/#request-structure
    const holdingInTokenArray = DUMMY_HOLDINGS.map(
      (holding) => holding.instrument_token
    );
    const message = { a: "subscribe", v: holdingInTokenArray };
    // Once the WS connection opens we send the request for the instruments subscribed as per the
    // docs in the message above
    ws.current.onopen = () => {
      console.log(`ws opened for ALL DUMMY_HOLDINGS`);
      console.log(message);
      ws.current.send(JSON.stringify(message));
    };
    ws.current.onclose = () => console.log(`ws closed for ALL DUMMY_HOLDINGS`);

    // Quick refresher: the useEffect return statement below runs before the useEffect hook, EXCEPT
    // EXCEPT for
    // 1. upon first render
    // 2. upon removal of DOM component
    return () => {
      ws.current.close();
    };
  }, [ws_url]);

  // This useEffect is for handling the onmessage WS event.
  // THIS IS WHERE MY PROBLEM BEGINS...
  useEffect(() => {
    // Simple guard statement
    if (!ws.current) return;

    // the onmessage event fires as expected, I just don't know how to read the e.data
    // which is supposed to contain the data I am looking for. I've read the docs
    // https://kite.trade/docs/connect/v3/websocket/#binary-market-data
    // tried .text() .arrayBuffer() but I can't make sense of the results.
    // My think my confusion is rooted in not knowing how to read Blob Data and converting
    // Blob into a format like the docs. Even if I just get an array of the Binary Data like
    // the docs I can handle it from there, I just don't know how to
    ws.current.onmessage = async (e) => {
      console.log(e.data);
      /**
       * e.data logs the following 
       MessageEvent {isTrusted: true, data: Blob, origin: "wss://ws.kite.trade", lastEventId: "", source: null, …}
          bubbles: false
          cancelBubble: false
          cancelable: false
          composed: false
          currentTarget: WebSocket {url: "wss://ws.kite.trade/?api_key=xxxxx&access_token=xxxx", readyState: 3, bufferedAmount: 0, onerror: null, onopen: ƒ, …}
          data: Blob {size: 48, type: ""}
          defaultPrevented: false
          eventPhase: 0
          isTrusted: true
          lastEventId: ""
          origin: "wss://ws.kite.trade"
          path: []
          ports: []
          returnValue: true
          source: null
          srcElement: WebSocket {url: "wss://ws.kite.trade/?api_key=xxxxx&access_token=xxxxxxxx", readyState: 3, bufferedAmount: 0, onerror: null, onopen: ƒ, …}
          target: WebSocket {url: "wss://ws.kite.trade/?api_key=xxxxx&access_token=xxxxxxxx", readyState: 3, bufferedAmount: 0, onerror: null, onopen: ƒ, …}
          timeStamp: 74468.20000000298
          type: "message"
          userActivation: null
       */

      console.log(await e.data.text());
      const message = JSON.parse(e.data);
      console.log("e: ", message);
    };
  }, []);

  // Once I am able to read the returned WS data, I want to populate some of it below for each of the
  // instruments.
  return (
    <>
      {!DUMMY_HOLDINGS.length ? (
        <Typography>No Holdings Found</Typography>
      ) : (
        DUMMY_HOLDINGS.map((item) => {
          return (
            <div style={{ "box-shadow": "0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2)" }}>
              <h3>
                Stock : {item.tradingsymbol} ({item.instrument_token})
              </h3>
              <p>Last Price: {item.last_price}</p>
            </div>
          );
        })
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default SomeComponent;
```

I just don't understand how to extract the data from binary to something I know what to do with. I've scratched my head endlessly on this for a while now, I think it would be easy for someone with experience in websockets, please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first convert Blob data recieved in the e.data response to an ArrayBuffer using

```
let t1 = await blob.arrayBuffer()
const a1 = new DataView(t1.slice(0,2)).getInt16() // number of packets
const b1 = new DataView(t1.slice(2,4)).getInt16() // bytes in packet
const c1_instrument_token = new DataView(t1.slice(4,8)).getInt32() // instrument token of packet 1
const c1_ltp = new DataView(t1.slice(8,12)).getInt32() // ltp of packet 1
```

and so on the key is to use the DataView to extract the underlying values. I swear my future self is going to forget I knew this and read this at some point and thank my past self. Hope this helps someone else also

Answer (score -1):

const text = await (new Response(e.data)).text();

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).